# use [NSString string] to create an empty String

Tags: ios, objective-c

use `[NSString string]` to create an empty String.what difference between`[NSString new]`?or it just same as `[NSString new]`.when i use `[NSString string]`,it will be call the 'init' method by Auto?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Calling `+new` is virtually the same as calling `+string`. They both return an instance of `NSString`.

`-init` is the designated initializer used for `+string` or `+new`, meaning you don't need to call it after that.

Comment: When using `new` or `string`, `init` need not and should not be called.

Comment: @mengtuo-zhu asked whether or not `-init` would be called automatically, which it is. I think you may have read my answer out of context...

Answer (score 0):

Under ARC those two are the same.

Even simpler is:

```
NSString *str = @"";
```

Comment: No, under under manual ref-counting they are not the same. `[NSString string]` and `@""` are autoreleased, `[NSString new]` and `[[NSString alloc] init]` aren't.